# SQL Subquery optimization multiple aggregate operations

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm trying to find the averages and sums of different tables and group by the project. I also want to condennse the returned table into a single row. 
So for my subquery I get this result

[image]

And the using the outer query I expect this: 
[image]

This is my sql code so far. It works but it's performance is very slow and I"m not sure why or how to optimize it.

```
select sum(sub.count) as count, avg(sub.opened) as opened,
avg(sub.clicked) as clicked, avg(sub.started_watching) as started_watching,
sum(sub.views) as views
from (
select p.id, count(e.id) as count, 
avg(e.opened) as opened, avg(e.read_email) as clicked,
avg(e.started_video) as started_watching, sum(e.views) as views
from projects p
inner join guests g
on g.project_id = p.id
inner join videos v
on v.guest_id = g.id
inner join emails e
on e.video_id=v.id
group by p.id) sub;
```

Comment: have you index . on the column involved in joins?   .. how many row you have in tables ? and the column you select in the suquery come alls from project?

Comment: The columns in the subquery come from different tables

Comment: please update the question and add  the table alias  to the columns name  .. so we can eval  the query better  .. and let meknow for the others qestiions

Comment: The subquery results can be inserted to temp table . Main query can be used to get from the temp table.

Comment: There's indexes for the column for the join. I'm not sure about how many rows in each table specifically but I believe project, guests, have many thousands

Comment: Unless I am missing something, why do you need a nested query? You don't have a where clause either.  So theoretically, you could get the totals in one query without the group by clause.

Comment: I want to aggregate on the email table rows by a unique project id and then further aggregate those values

Answer (score 0):

looking to your query  the main problem is related to the creation of subquery  result
so is important improve this query eg adding proper index  on columns involved in join for each table 
adn eventually add  composite index for column used in select  ( after the column used in join )

```
  Select  sum(sub.count) as count
        , avg(sub.opened) as opened
        , avg(sub.clicked) as clicked
        , avg(sub.started_watching) as started_watching
        , sum(sub.views) as views
  from (
    select p.id
        , count(e.id) as count
        , avg(e.opened) as opened
        , avg(e.read_email) as clicked
        , avg(e.started_video) as started_watching
        , sum(e.views) as views
    from projects p
    inner join guests g on g.project_id = p.id
    inner join videos v on v.guest_id = g.id
    inner join emails e on e.video_id=v.id
    group by p.id
  ) sub;
```

so be sure you have proper index on

```
guests  (project_id)
videos  (guest_id)
emails  (video_id, id, opened, read_email,started_video, views)

and obvious on projects (id)
```